# How to overcome screen size issue?

Tags: android, canvas

I draw a tic tac toe game UI using canvas. When I run it on Samsung mobile then this UI is perfect, but when I run it on Motorola it gives me a screen size problem.

```
package com.example.asad.tictoe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by asad on 5/25/16.
 */
public class caanvas extends View {
    ;

    public caanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        canvas.drawLine(250, 300, 250, 1000, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(480, 300, 480, 1000, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(40, 520, 695, 520, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(40, 785, 695, 785, paint);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        float x = ev.getX();
        float y = ev.getY();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is guide about supporting multiple screen as it's said in best practice section "Do not use hard coded pixel values in your application code" so you should take screen size using this.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int h = metrics.heightPixels;
int w = metrics.widthPixels;
```

Then draw canvas depends on screen size.

In your case you are in View class so you can use

```
int h = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels
int w = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html